# Select statement based on attributes in xml records as varchar in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a table with 2 columns, `ID (Int)` and `ResponseData (Varchar(MAX))` in which I stored XML text as shown here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapTest:Response xmlns:soapTest="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="2.0">
   <soap:Issuer xmlns:soap="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://abc.sa/</soap:Issuer>
   <soapTest:Status>
      <soapTest:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" />
   </soapTest:Status>
   <soap:Assertion xmlns:soap="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" Version="2.0">
      <soap:AttributeStatement>
         <soap:Attribute Name="http://abc/xxx/englishFirstName" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
            <soap:AttributeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">JACK</soap:AttributeValue>
         </soap:Attribute>
     <soap:Attribute Name="http://abc/xxx/englishName" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
            <soap:AttributeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">Jack Mike</soap:AttributeValue>
         </soap:Attribute>
         <soap:Attribute Name="http://abc/xxx/lang" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
            <soap:AttributeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">en</soap:AttributeValue>
         </soap:Attribute>
         <soap:Attribute Name="http://abc/xxx/dob" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
            <soap:AttributeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">Thu Jan 21 00:00:00 AST 1988</soap:AttributeValue>
         </soap:Attribute>
         <soap:Attribute Name="http://abc/xxx/userid" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
            <soap:AttributeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">1010026175</soap:AttributeValue>
         </soap:Attribute>
         <soap:Attribute Name="http://abc/xxx/nationality" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
            <soap:AttributeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">Canadian</soap:AttributeValue>
         </soap:Attribute>
         <soap:Attribute Name="http://abc/xxx/englishGrandFatherName" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
            <soap:AttributeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">test</soap:AttributeValue>
         </soap:Attribute>
      </soap:AttributeStatement>
   </soap:Assertion>
</soapTest:Response>
```

Now I have more than 100 records in the table, some response/xml records don't have tag/node "Attribute" with attribute "Name=http://abc/xxx/englishName", how can I return **all** these records that don't have this node?

For example

First record has below tag/attribute:

```
<soap:Attribute Name="http://abc/xxx/englishName" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
 <soap:AttributeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">Jack Mike</soap:AttributeValue>
     </soap:Attribute>
```

The second record doesn't have it, the response came without attribute Name englishName...

I want to return all records with its ID to know which doesn't has this attribute, the result to be

```
ID                    responseData
---------------------------------------------------------------
12                    <?xml version="1.0" encodxxxxxxxx
15                    <?xml version="1.0" encodxxxxxxxx
87                    <?xml version="1.0" encodxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: If the `responseData` column stores only XML - ***why*** isn't it of type `XML` ?? That would make things a lot easier (and more efficient, too!)

Comment: It is not clear what you are looking for. Please provide the following: (1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table() plus INSERT statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic.
(3) Desired output based on the sample data.

Comment: marc_s --- actually this database since 3 years for a company, I cannot change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the vague requirements, please try the following.

> SQL

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, ResponseData NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl
VALUES (N'<soapTest:Response xmlns:soapTest="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
                   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="2.0">
    <soap:Issuer xmlns:soap="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://abc.sa/</soap:Issuer>
    <soapTest:Status>
        <soapTest:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/>
    </soapTest:Status>
    <soap:Assertion xmlns:soap="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" Version="2.0">
        <soap:AttributeStatement>
            <soap:Attribute Name="http://abc/xxx/englishFirstName"
                            NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
                <soap:AttributeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                                     xsi:type="xs:string">JACK</soap:AttributeValue>
            </soap:Attribute>
            <soap:Attribute Name="http://abc/xxx/englishName"
                            NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
                <soap:AttributeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                                     xsi:type="xs:string">Jack Mike</soap:AttributeValue>
            </soap:Attribute>
            <soap:Attribute Name="http://abc/xxx/lang"
                            NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
                <soap:AttributeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                                     xsi:type="xs:string">en</soap:AttributeValue>
            </soap:Attribute>
            <soap:Attribute Name="http://abc/xxx/dob"
                            NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
                <soap:AttributeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                                     xsi:type="xs:string">Thu Jan 21 00:00:00 AST 1988</soap:AttributeValue>
            </soap:Attribute>
            <soap:Attribute Name="http://abc/xxx/userid"
                            NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
                <soap:AttributeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                                     xsi:type="xs:string">1010026175</soap:AttributeValue>
            </soap:Attribute>
            <soap:Attribute Name="http://abc/xxx/nationality"
                            NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
                <soap:AttributeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                                     xsi:type="xs:string">Canadian</soap:AttributeValue>
            </soap:Attribute>
            <soap:Attribute Name="http://abc/xxx/englishGrandFatherName"
                            NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
                <soap:AttributeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                                     xsi:type="xs:string">test</soap:AttributeValue>
            </soap:Attribute>
        </soap:AttributeStatement>
    </soap:Assertion>
</soapTest:Response>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion'
    , 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol' AS [soapTest]), rs AS
(
   SELECT *, TRY_CAST(ResponseData AS XML) AS [xml_data]
   FROM @tbl
)
SELECT ID
    , col.query('.') AS [xml_data]
FROM rs AS tbl
    CROSS APPLY tbl.[xml_data].nodes('/soapTest:Response') AS tab(col)
WHERE col.exist('Assertion/AttributeStatement/Attribute/@Name[.="http://abc/xxx/englishName"]') = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks, its working fine without declare the table, I just used your code starting from WITH XMLNAMESPACES.

Comment: Glad to hear that the suggested answer is working for you. You need to provide a minimal, reproducible example while asking a question. That's exactly the reason why I created that DDL and sample data population. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: but why if the xml data has arabic name, it is not working, when I running the query, I found this error                   Msg 9402, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
XML parsing: line 1, character 38, unable to switch the encoding

Comment: You need to open a separate new thread on the Arabic issue. Please provide the following: (1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT statements. (2) What you need to do, i.e. logic. (3) Desired output based on the sample data.